# How to properly remove an UIImageView from UIScrollView?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I'm developing an app that i need to load many images in a view using Xcode 4.5.2

So, At the top, I have a `UIView`, inside of this `UIView`, i have `UIScrollView` to display many images,i'm using this `UIScrollView` in pagingEnabled mode. As i have many images to load, i know that it cannot be possible to load at once. So, i decided to add or remove  if need be.

When the app starts, i've loaded three images in `UIScrollView`, when user passes to image 2,
i want to remove image 0 from `UIScrollView`.When i try to remove the image 0,i got totally white screen.The funny part is that if i dont try to remove image 0,when user passes to image 3, i want to load a new image(image 4) to `UIScrollView`, and remove image 1.So far, I'm able to do this. Basically,my apps works just fine, but when i want to remove the first(**at index 0**)image,I got totally white screen on the screen.

Do you have any idea why i'm getting this behaviour ? I got neither warning,nor error. How is it possible that i'm able to remove all the other images but not the image 0 ?

Thank you.

```
     -(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{ 
static NSInteger currentPage = 0 ;
CGFloat pageWidth = self.scrollView.frame.size.width ;
float fractionalPage = self.scrollView.contentOffset.x / pageWidth ;
NSLog(@"%f",fractionalPage);
if(fractionalPage == currentPage+1)
{
    NSLog(@"Swipe Left");
    currentPage++;
    NSLog(@"Current page :%d",currentPage);

    [self setLayoutImages:kLeft] ;
}
else if(fractionalPage+1 ==currentPage)
{
    NSLog(@"Swipe Right");
    currentPage--;
    NSLog(@"Current page :%d",currentPage);
    [self setLayoutImages:kRight];
}
```

}

```
-(void)setLayoutImages:(Direction )direction
{
int currentPage = self.scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollViewWidth ;
if(direction == kLeft)
{
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(((currentPage+2) * scrollViewWidth), 350.0f);
    if(![self.scrollView viewWithTag:currentPage+1])
    {
        NSString *imageName = @"iPhone.png" ;
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:image ] ;
        imageView.tag  = currentPage+1 ;
        CGRect frame = imageView.frame ;
        frame.size.height = imageHeight;
        frame.size.width = scrollViewWidth ;
        frame.origin.x = (currentPage+1) * scrollViewWidth ;
        frame.origin.y = 0 ;
        imageView.frame = frame ;
        if (currentPage>2) { //To be able to remove the first image,i need to add equal here,but i got white screen.
            [[self.scrollView viewWithTag:(currentPage -2)]removeFromSuperview ] ;            }
        [self.scrollView addSubview:imageView ] ;
    }
}
else if(direction == kRight)
{
    if(![self.scrollView viewWithTag:currentPage-1] && currentPage >0)
    {
        NSString *imageName = @"gs.jpeg";
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:image ];
        imageView.tag = currentPage-1 ;
        CGRect frame = imageView.frame ;
        frame.size.height = imageHeight ;
        frame.size.width = scrollViewWidth ;
        frame.origin.x = (currentPage-1)*scrollViewWidth ;
        frame.origin.y = 0 ;
        imageView.frame = frame ;
        [[self.scrollView viewWithTag:currentPage+2]removeFromSuperview ] ;
        [self.scrollView addSubview:imageView ];
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Some code would be helpful. Could you post the code that is adding and removing the UIImageViews from the UISCrollView

Comment: firstly, i don't think currentPage needs to be static. Secondly, try making your views start with a tag of 1 not 0, as 0 is the default for an untagged view if i remember correctly, and this might be causing the problem.

Comment: @Bergasms, currentPage has to be static.But,the other thins u said, i'll try.

Comment: @Bergasms,you're right.It worked right now.Add your comment as an answer,i'll accept.

Comment: cool, glad that worked out for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making your views start with a tag of 1 not 0, as 0 is the default for an untagged view if i remember correctly, and this might be causing the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can Give each one of three deferant `Tag` and reuse it by `[[view viewWithtag:tag] removeFromSuperView]` or you can try ready project called [iCarousel](https://github.com/Omarj/iCarousel) made by `nicklockwood` it is an wonderful project.

it can be `horizontal`  and `vertical`

[image]

Comment: You can take a look at my code, i've been using `tag` property and all the methods you just mentioned.But,thanks anyway,by the way,it's not possible to use iCarousel in my case.